# Clothes dryer causing humidity problems in garage - would extraction fan help?

Tags: exhaust-fan, humidity, laundry, dehumidifier

We have a double garage with a high ceiling which is also where our laundry is.

We have a problem with humidity in there due to the clothes dryer being in there which is used very regularly.

This is resulting in mould on the ceiling, and my tools going rusty.

We bought a dehumidifier and if that runs all day it extracts a lot of water but still doesn't seem to be able to keep up. Leaving the window open doesn't make any difference and even if I leave the garage door open for half an hour it doesn't help much.

I want to know if I add an extraction fan in the ceiling that draws air into the roof space is that likely to make any difference.

Also, if extraction fans draw the moisture into the roof space will that cause humidity problems in there instead?

Comment: Is it possible to extend the exhaust vent of the dryer through an outside wall?

Comment: Agreed. You need to vent the dryer to the outside. Blowing that moisture into the attic will cause mold and rot in your attic, possibly water damage on your walls and ceilings when it condenses,  and may eventually cause roof damage. As a plus, venting the dryer outside can shorten your drying time and save some energy ($$$).

Comment: Where does the dryer vent out to and is it a condensing type?

Comment: @ratchetfreak, it's just an electric dryer that vents out the front.

Comment: @EricSimpson, if an exhaust fan is going to do damage elsewhere then i guess that's out. I was hoping for a simpler solution than venting outside but oh well. If it was up to me I would use it less or put it outside, but wife has more say in this than I do :)

Comment: You need to get the moisture out of your building, and the best way by far is to vent it directly out. Otherwise, You Will Have Problems.

Comment: Does your dryer somehow not have a port on the back to hook a vent duct up to?

Comment: Could you give us the brand and model of the dryer?

Comment: newer HE washers spin the clothes a LOT drier than the old top-loading ones, so that might help if you were looking to invest in energy improvements anyway...

Comment: It's an old Hoover (Australia) dryer with no rear vent option. Sounds like I need a new washing machine and dryer with external venting (& wife?).

Comment: Aren't Australian dryers vented in the out back?

Comment: Nice one @DrMoishePippik!

Comment: @EricSimpson, if you want to post your comment as an answer I will accept it to close this question. Related question: bathrooms usually have an exhaust fan into the roof space - would they suffer the same problem and if so why do they use them?

Comment: @johna, Bathroom fans that vent into the attic space absolutely do cause problems. They usually vent somewhere other than the attic space (e.g. roof), though some ways are worse than others (e.g. through a soffit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to vent the dryer to the outside. Blowing moisture from your dryer, or bath vent, into the attic will cause mold and rot in your attic, possibly water damage on your walls and ceilings when it condenses, and may eventually cause roof damage. As a plus, venting the dryer outside can shorten your drying time and save some energy ($$$).